# googlecloudappengine javaランタイム8から11に変更

Tags: java, eclipse

googlecloudappengineでjavaのアプリケーションeclipseをjavaを使用して作成している者です。
googlecloudappengineのjava8のruntimeサポート期限が迫っているためruntimeを8から11に変更しようと考えています。
runtimeを8から11に変更する際に実施しなければならないことは何でしょうか
現在実施したことはeclipseのプロジェクトのjreとappengine-web.xmlのruntimeを8から11に変更しました。
またソースコードを変更する際はJDKのバージョンを変えるのでしょうか。
ご協力をよろしくお願いいたします。